# The link to "move this discussion to chat" is too small in the mobile view

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design, mobile-web

The link to `automatically move this discussion to chat?` is a smaller size than the preceeding text, `Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to`. **Shouldn't the whole block of text be the same size?** At the very least, I don't think the size should change within the sentence (**Would you like to** <sup><sub>automatically move this discussion to chat?</sub></sup>)...

As you can see in the screenshots, this occurs on the mobile version of the site across many browsers (even a desktop browser). The text has a consistent size on the normal view, and the smaller size in the mobile view, matching the normal link size, leads me to the conclusion that this is a bug (i.e. unintentional).

---

**On a phone:**

The bug occurs in Opera Mobile 12, Firefox Mobile 14 and the Android 2.3 browser, on Android 2.3.

[image: Screenshot-Phone-Opera]
[image: Screenshot-Phone-Firefox]
[image: Screenshot-Phone-Android]

---

**On a PC:**

Firefox 13, mobile version of the site

[image: Screenshot-PC-Firefox]

On Firefox 13, desktop version of the site:

[image: Screenshot-PC-Firefox-comparison]

Comment: What exactly is wrong with having it appear slightly differently from the surrounding text?  It's a link - it **should** be differentiated from the rest of the "non clickable" text...By size, by color, etc...

Comment: The `move this discussion to chat` message should appear again when you attempt to add another comment to that thread...

Comment: @Lix By colour, sure. But the size difference looks odd, along with making it harder to click/press the link. it's not exactly a convention to have links a different size, anyway. And I *did* attempt to add another comment, where the message did not appear - if it did, I would not be remarking on its absence!

Comment: I've edited with more reasoning for why I think it's a bug, i.e. unintentional. If this was actually an intentional effect, then could someone let me know and I'll change this to a feature request for the text to be the same size?

Comment: I don't understand why you have tagged it as _bug_?! The formatting for both the devices could be different and it can't be said as a _bug_ if you see different formatting on mobile as compared to on desktop.

Comment: @Bongs The inconsistent size seems odd to me, as if someone forgot to set a style/size for the link. I'll also note that this is the *only* place on SE I've seen with a different text size for a link compared to surrounding text. If you still think this shouldn't be tagged as a bug, I'll happily change it to a feature request :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be deployed in the next builds (`rev 2236` on meta and `rev 1600` on main).